# Filtering on Linq that contains Custom Type using ODataQueryOptions

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, odata, unit-of-work

While implementing Kendo Grid in MVC that perform server side operations, I find myself in a tricky situation, i.e., I have to filter, sort, paged my data using linq. And all information I got is in ODataQueryOptions type.

(Not sure if it is necessary to mention or not, but for the sake of completeness, we perform query operations through UnitOfWork pattern)

So operation that perform query is copied below:

```
public static List<T> GetT(this IRepositoryAsync<T> repository, ODataQueryOptions<T> options)
    {
        var query = repository.Query().Tracking(false).Include(x => x.T2)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                P1 = s.P1,
                P2 = s.P2,
                P3 = s.T2.P1 + "," + s.T2.P2
            })
            .Select(s => new T1
            {
                P1 = s.P1,
                P2 = s.P2,
                P3 = s.P3
            });

        if (options.Skip != null)
            query = query.Skip(options.Skip.Value);
        if (options.Top != null)
            query = query.Take(options.Top.Value);

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Now, I want to know if there is option to apply remaining oData options to linq query (as you can see $skip and $top is already applied, how can we apply OrderByQueryOption and FilterQueryOption).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [OrderByQueryOption](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Query/OrderByQueryOption.cs) there is a property `OrderByNodes` you can use this to construct your query, but in [FilterQueryOption](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Query/FilterQueryOption.cs), it's hard to translate the FilterClause, you need the FilterBinder to do this for you but it's not public in 5.9.1, it's public in [6.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/6.0.0-beta2).

Comment: My be getting something of type Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> directly from OrderByQueryOption would help me (as method that perform Order by in UnitOfWork expect this type)